# What is wrong with my SQL Syntax

Tags: mysql

```
create table const_category (
    cat_id int(8) not null auto_increment primary key,
    cat_label varchar(150)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table const_subcategory (
    subcat_id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key,
        subcat_label varchar(150),
        cat_id int(9) not null,
        FOREIGN KEY cat_id REFERENCES const_category(cat_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Are you getting an error message or what?

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? It's not our job to decipher your code with no instructions.

Comment: Error message from SQL Fiddle: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES const_category(cat_id) )ENGINE=InnoDB' at line 1: `

Answer (score 2):

Compare your code with this code from the MySQL manual:

```
CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT, 
    parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) 
        REFERENCES parent(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

You don't have parentheses around the column name in your foreign key declaration.

Reference:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

Have your constraint name in parenthesis like `FOREIGN KEY (cat_id)`

```
create table const_subcategory (
    subcat_id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key,
        subcat_label varchar(150),
        cat_id int(9) not null,
        FOREIGN KEY (cat_id) REFERENCES const_category(cat_id)
);
```

See a fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b7cd